# How can I check for unicode or escape sequences in a string?

Tags: python, string, unicode, escaping

I have a dictionary list of words, some of the words containing sequences like so:

`K\xc3\xb6LN` or `KöLN` when displayed properly.

I'd like to purge the list of such words, such that they contain plain ascii characters only.  How can I do a simple True/False check to see if a string contains such sequences?

Comment: Which ASCII characters are plain? What is so terrifying about using Unicode? Would you prefer to change that to "KoLN" and retain it?

Comment: @JohnMachin this is for a dictionary attack experiment. words were taken from /usr/share/dict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`str.isalpha()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) may be of assistance here:

```
>>> 'KöLN'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'K\xc3\xb6LN'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'Cologne'.isalpha()
True
```

Filtering:

```
>>> [word for word in ('KöLN', 'K\xc3\xb6LN', 'Cologne') if word.isalpha()]
['Cologne']
```

Comment: It is important to be careful, though: u'KöLN'.isalpha() gives True while 'KöLN'.isalpha() gives False [just tried it in 2.7 in a UTF-8 encoded file.]  I think I'd simply try turning the string into ascii and decide based on whether an exception was raised instead.